# Laravel não carrega parte Visual

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Quando entro no meu local host (http://localhost/project/public/login) a página é carregada porém o design não, ficando assim.

OBS: Eu só coloquei o php artisan make: auth mais nada[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não vai mesmo! está configurado errado é por isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aperte Ctrl+U e verifique o código fonte a sua aplicação.

Ele não está encontrando os arquivos de estilos definidos entre `<head></head>`. Estão no caminho errado por algum motivo.

Em especial o arquivo bootstrap.min.css

No Laravel 5 você pode tentar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: Olá, no meu caso eu hospedei o app na pasta public_html da Hostinger... e no lugar de assets/css tenho que usar public/css, está correto?